# Rodar programa em FullScreen no Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, cmd, fullscreen

Olá tenho um projeto já finalizado, ele foi escrito na linguagem C como faço para que o mesmo rode em fullscreen no windows 7?

Tem alguma biblioteca para isso? Estive procurando na internet porém não encontrei nada do tipo.

Comment: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/196103

Comment: Precisa dar mais detalhes de como é esse programa. Quando você diz `cmd` quer dizer que é console? Você quer que o `cmd` fique *full screen* mesmo? Não é maximizado?

Comment: Coloca um trecho do código do início para vermos como está.

Comment: preciso que um programa em C rode em fullscreen

Comment: Amigo, você pode tentar seguir esses passos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-a_kdWMW28

Comment: Obrigado @Renato_Souza_Delphi isso era para um trabalho da faculdade rs... de qualquer forma obrigado a ajuda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode tentar maximizar:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
HWND hwndConsole = NULL;
hwndConsole = FindWindow(NULL, "Test.exe"); // TODO: pegar o hwnd do processo atual
if(NULL != hwndConsole)
{
   SetForegroundWindow(hwndConsole);
   ShowWindow(hwndConsole, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

Fonte: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/196103

Ou em windows mais antigos (antes do Windows 7):
Você pode tentar chamar a função **SetConsoleDisplayMode**, com a opção **CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE** (1)

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346339/194717

Documentação: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: vou tentar.. vlw

Comment: qual a biblioteca? windows.h?

Comment: @HiagoSouza Winuser.h